# iOS instruments, cannot not launch any app on iPad. Instruments fails silently

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode6, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am trying to launch an application on iPad (iPad 4) connected to my Mac via instruments. The same command works fine on another iPad (iPad Air) when run from  same Mac. Below is the command I am using to launch the application:

```
instruments -w [ios_device_uuid] -t [path_to_trace_template] [app_name]
```

When this command is run on my Ipad 4, instruments does not throw any error but I see the app does not launch. I have ensured that the provisioning profiles exist on the iPad, UI automation is enabled from the iPad settings. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: Strange. Any particular reason you're not using Xcode to launch Instruments?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to automate my tests to be run on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have `Debug` build on your iPad, i.e. an app signed with a debug provisioning profile, or directly installed/run from Xcode.

Automation and profiling through instruments does not work with Ad-Hoc or AppStore builds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The app build surely is a debug build, since I am able to install and launch on another iPad.  Any other suggestions?  I was wondering if there was a setting to enable developer mode on iPad ?